# want to do some task in editText.setOnTouchListener only once and not each time

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

i want to do something like when user click on editText then it gets enabled to be edit (by default it gets disabled in xml) and a toast(and some more buttons) should appear only once, not every time.

i create following logic for this:-

```
edt_title.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {

Crouton.showText(ShowActivity.this, "Editing Mode Enabled",Style.INFO);

welcome.animate(getApplicationContext(), gallery, R.anim.fab_jump_from_down,  300);
                edt_title.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            }
            return false;}
    });
```

problem is that it gets called everytime when user tap on editText,
is there any way to do it only once when editText gets clicked.
May be it possible with use sharedPreference but it will be better if i can do it without using of sharedPreference.

Thanks in advance :)
Nishu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
edt_title.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    boolean called = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (!called && MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
            Crouton.showText(ShowActivity.this, "Editing Mode Enabled",Style.INFO);
            welcome.animate(getApplicationContext(), gallery, R.anim.fab_jump_from_down,  300);
            edt_title.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            called = true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a global var that you use like flag and use for one simple time

```
boolean flagOneTime = true;
```

and add this inside your listener

```
if( flagOneTime )
{
   // do something and disable flag
   flagOneTime = false;
}
```